# CentOS Firewall Issues on GCE

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying out a "Hello World" exercise for GCE. First, I went with CentOS Image, added the instance, installed Apache, added the Firewall. All looks good as far as configuration is concerned. When I try to access the web page from outside, it cannot reach the page.

The Local Apache Server is running, from the local instance I can do a curl and all is well.

On the other hand, if I try out the same exact steps with the Debian distribution, everything works smoothly.

I saw another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450997/http-access-on-gce-instance-after-firewall-rule-added) that mentioned about additional firewall settings but I have not tried that out and I am not sure why it should be done either.

Can anyone explain if the CentOS setup does need additional Firewall settings and what those are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS defaults to a restrictive operating system level firewall (using iptables), while debian defaults to a permissive one. You can relax the firewall rules on CentOS as well. When running on Compute Engine, the service level firewall will only allow connections from the internet via configured ports.

To relax the CentOS firewall:

```
$ sudo iptables -D  INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Then test that your connections work as expected. To save this configuration across system reboots:

```
$ /sbin/service iptables save
```

See the [IPTables HowTo on the CentOS wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables) for more information about working with iptables on CentOS.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question or two here. While it is good that this configuration is saved across Reboots, I wanted to know if these changes could be saved as a system image/snapshot on a PD, via which I can bring up future instances so that I don't have to repeat these steps? Should the documentation in the GCE Quick Start contain these additional steps for CentOS image?

Comment: These changes will be saved across reboots & for new instances booting from the same PD. You can also save any PD as an instance or snapshot which allows you to create new PDs with the same content. Snapshots are easier to create & manage. Images are useful if you need to export the image to share across projects. This seems beyond the scope of Quick Start to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need free the ports in the cloud console.

Watch this video that explain the proccess.

[Google Compute Engine Test Drive](http://j.mp/1h7Ith5)

Comment: This video is great though it covers the Debian distribution, which did not need any ports to be freed and which I verified that it works ok.