# Cant VNC into Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have spent a couple days trying to install software on Google Compute Engine (GCE) and then remotely access it from either my windows pc or local linux machine.

I can install software, like Google Chrome, etc. but can't open the applications as I keep getting display issues (understandably because GCE is headless). So I'm trying to VNC into the GCE instance.

**I have tried installing the following on the server: (Instance Name is "talend")**

vnc4server: I get output saying the server is running and everything looks good. Only error I get is a Language error like the following:

`steven@talend:~$ vnc4server -geometry 1440x900 :1
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:LANGUAGE = (unset),LC_ALL = (unset),LANG = "en_ZA.UTF-8"are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
A VNC server is already running as :1`

and

`steven@talend:~$ vnc4server -geometry 1440x900 :2
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:LANGUAGE = (unset),LC_ALL = (unset),LANG = "en_ZA.UTF-8"are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
New 'talend:2 (steven)' desktop is talend:2
Starting applications specified in /home/steven/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/steven/.vnc/talend:2.log`

**Remote Access: Using TightVNC client via Windows**

I get the following message:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

**Remote Access: Using Vinagre via Linux**

```
Connection to host 8.34.210.67::5902 was closed.
```

**Via Google Compute Engine Web Console:**

Tried changing to static ip > No Difference

Tried adding `tcp:80` with `Source: 0.0.0.0/0` > No Difference

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this but I can't seem to find it. Any help will be appreciated and then will post a link to the final solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to configure three settings to all agree on the same port:

- The port vnc4server is listening on.
- A Compute Engine firewall rule to allow traffic on that port.
- The port TightVNC is attempting to connect to.

From the error message "Connection to host 8.34.210.67::5902 was closed.", it looks like TightVNC is trying to connect to 5902. Assuming that vnc4server is also listening on that port, you should add a Compute Engine firewall rule to allow that port.

Visit the Console at https://cloud.google.com/console, click on your project, then Compute Engine, then Networks. Click the "Create new" next to "Firewalls" and add a new rule with  tcp:5902 set in the Ports/Protocols field.

If you're running on Centos, there is an additional step to disable the local firewall as well: [CentOS Firewall Issues on GCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565641/centos-firewall-issues-on-gce)

Comment: Thanks Brian. I got in via TightVNC after adding the tcp:5902 rule to the firewall. Now I have the next problem which is being able to launch graphical applications like Chrome or in my case Talend Open Studio. I get cannot launch display errors but I would guess that for the Linux section. Running DEBIAN default install that comes with GCE Instance.

Comment: Xwindows supports multiple displays, and graphical apps default to using display 0, which is usually the local display. vnc4server appears to be using display 2 ("desktop is talend:2") If you're able to connect to an interactive desktop via VNC, that's usually enough - the desktop knows to start apps on the same display. However, it sounds like that's not working for you. My guess is that the apps are trying to use display 0. If so, there are two routes to making things work: change vnc4server settings to start as display 0, or start the apps pointing at display 2.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I managed to get it to work. For everyone else, this is what I did. Run the following commands in the terminal: $ vnc4server -geometry 1440x900 :1... and then $ export DISPLAY=:1 . I then used tightvnc from windows machine and connected to the ipaddress and added the display number to the end like this... 123.12.12.123:1 and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Guacamole and Tomcat to access your desktop via a browser or VNC client.

Use Aptitude or apt-get to install guacamole-tomcat.  I have the VNC port in firewall settings (via tags) as well as http and https.  I've set up a "guacamole" tag to use with the firewall as well.  Your GCE instance will need these tags assigned.  There are some configs to do via /etc/guacamole/ for user/login etc, but essentially it goes like this...

Once installed, the default ports are 8080.  So browse to http://:8080/guacamole/ and you will get a Guacamole login screen.  When you login, you will have links to click that start your desktop in a browser window.

You can also VNC directly (no browser) via :5901 - or whatever port you configured Guacamole with.  It's best of course to have set up a st

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
```

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

if it is not similar flush:

```
sudo iptables -F
```