# Setting up chrome remote desktop on google cloud compute vm linux instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, chrome-remote-desktop

I'm trying to set up GUI access to a linux VM on google compute engine. I've followed the advice here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/tN9oZs8xWps

I can get as far as getting the instance to show up on the "My Computers" section of the CRD app, but it is grayed out.

I'm wondering if I need to mess around with firewall settings, or try a different desktop (I've been trying cinnamon). I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: this might help: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gtdUOLy5G_A

Answer (score 1):

You definitely have to open the ports to connect, so you will have to use a [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls). Cloud Platform has an [implicit deny ingress rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules). It is explained in the thread you posted that also if you are [using CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565641/centos-firewall-issues-on-gce) there is an additional steps to disable a firewall rule.